# Neo4j value in a time range and total value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to neo4j. I am writing queries for bitcoin transactions. I want the miners, their reward in a time range and their total reward in row

for example (name, value in time range, total value)

```
Binance  1500 100000
Slush    1000 29900000
```

My first query for the value in time range:

```
MATCH (m:Miner)-[rel:GUESSED]->(b:Block)
with m as m, rel as rel, b as b
WHERE apoc.date.parse(b.time,'s') >= apoc.date.parse("2021-04-01 05:29:58", 's') and apoc.date.parse(b.time,'s') <= apoc.date.parse("2021-04-01 08:15:45", 's')
return m.name, b.time, sum(rel.reward)
```

My second query for the total value

```
MATCH (m:Miner)-[rel:GUESSED]->(b:Block)
with m as m, rel as rel, b as b
return m.name, b.time, sum(rel.reward)
```

Is there a way to combine the two results in one row?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an idea of your data but try below query. It will sum up the rewards then filter the miner based on the time between 5:39 and 8:15.

```
MATCH (m:Miner)-[rel:GUESSED]->(b:Block)
with m, b, sum(rel.reward) as reward
MATCH (m)-[:GUESSED]->(b:Block)
WHERE apoc.date.parse(b.time,'s') >= apoc.date.parse("2021-04-01 05:29:58", 's') 
  and apoc.date.parse(b.time,'s') <= apoc.date.parse("2021-04-01 08:15:45", 's')
return m.name, b.time, reward
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but the output of this query is only the sum in a time range. I want to have the sum in a time range and the total sum (independent of a time range), both in a row. The reward is a property of the 'GUESSED' rel

Comment: please give us sample data wherein a lot of Block nodes with block time values. Then expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Does this works for you:

```
MATCH (m:Miner)-[rel:GUESSED]->(b:Block)
with m.name AS minerName, sum (rel.award) AS totalReward
MATCH (m1:Miner)-[rel:GUESSED]->(b:Block)
WHERE apoc.date.parse(b.time,'s') >= apoc.date.parse("2021-04-01 05:29:58", 's') AND apoc.date.parse(b.time,'s') <= apoc.date.parse("2021-04-01 08:15:45", 's') 
WITH minerName, totalReward, sum(rel.award) AS rewardWithinTimePeriod
WHERE minerName = m1.name
RETURN minerName, totalReward, rewardWithinTimePeriod
```